# Why I can't use matplotlib.pyplot in Spyder?

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I'm taking an online course. In the exercise I have to plot two histogram comparing rain vs no rain ridership, here is the code I used in online course.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def entries_histogram(turnstile_weather):

    plt.figure()
    ax = turnstile_weather['ENTRIESn_hourly'][turnstile_weather['rain'] == 0].plot(kind = 'hist', title = 'Histogram of ENTRIESn_hourly', bins = 30)
    turnstile_weather['ENTRIESn_hourly'][turnstile_weather['rain'] == 1].plot(kind = 'hist', bins = 30, ax=ax)
    ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
    ax.set_xlabel('ENTRIESn_hourly')
    return plt
```

It works perfect in the webpage of online course but when I installed Anaconda and use Spyder software to run the exact same code. It shows me an error:

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py in plot_series(series, label, kind, use_index, rot, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, ax, style, grid, legend, logx, logy, secondary_y, **kwds)
   2231         klass = _plot_klass[kind]
   2232     else:
-> 2233         raise ValueError('Invalid chart type given %s' % kind)
   2234 
   2235     """

ValueError: Invalid chart type given hist
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Quick answer*: You can fix the problem by updating `pandas` to the latest version:

```
conda install pandas
```

The `kind='hist'` option was added to `Series.plot()` in version `0.15.0`. Your code example should work with latest version `0.15.2`

For more information, see the enhancement section of the [release notes of  0.15.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0150-enhancements) and the [pull request 7809](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7809/) on github.

Comment: I still have this issue. I installed matplotlib and even followed the above-suggested solution but it does not work for me: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-a0d2faabd9e9>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'